KafkaTestUtils consume from multiple topics
In my tests, I want to make sure that the method with some business logic successfully sends messages to multiple topics. So I wrote the following test method:
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void shouldSuccessfullyPassThroughPipeline() {
        // init

        try (
                var dlqConsumer = KafkaIntegrationTestUtils.createConsumer(
                        String.class,
                        kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(null),
                        "dlq-topic"
                );
                var firstConsumer = KafkaIntegrationTestUtils.createConsumer(
                        String.class,
                        kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(null),
                        "first-output-topic"
            );
                var secondConsumer = KafkaIntegrationTestUtils.createConsumer(
                        String.class,
                        kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(null),
                        "second-output-topic"
            )
    ) {
            kafkaTemplate.send(new ProducerRecord<>(getInputTopicName(), key, value)).get();

            var dlqResult = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(dlqConsumer);
            var firstResult = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(firstConsumer);
            var secondResult = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(secondConsumer);

        //asserts
    }
}

KafkaIntegrationTestUtils class:
public class KafkaIntegrationTestUtils {

    public static <V> Consumer<String, V> createConsumer(Class<V> valueClass, Map<String, Object> properties, String topicName) {
        properties.put(CommonClientConfigs.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, Instancio.create(String.class));

        var factory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                properties,
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<V>(valueClass, false)
        );

        var consumer = factory.createConsumer();

        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topicName));

        return consumer;
    }
}

application-test.yml
spring:
  kafka:
    listener:
      ack-mode: record
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: latest
      enable-auto-commit: false
    producer:
      acks: 1

When I run this test I have to wait 180 seconds, because there are no records in dql-topic (which is correct), and getRecords for the firstConsumer/secondConsumer returns either no records (which is incorrect). If I change order of getRecords calls e.g.:
    var firstResult = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(firstConsumer);
    var secondResult = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(secondConsumer);
    var dlqResult = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(dlqConsumer);

I will get non empty firstResult and empty secondResult (which is incorrect) and dlqResult.
I don’t understand what’s going on, because each consumer has a unique group and auto-offset-reset: latest, but maybe I’m missing something.

UPDATE
If I create single consumer for multiple topics e.g.:
public class KafkaIntegrationTestUtils {

    public static Consumer<String, String> createConsumer(Map<String, Object> properties, List<String> topicNames) {
        properties.put(CommonClientConfigs.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, Instancio.create(String.class));

        var factory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                properties,
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new StringDeserializer()
        );

        var consumer = factory.createConsumer();

        consumer.subscribe(topicNames);

        return consumer;
   }
}

And use it in my test:
try (
            var consumer = KafkaIntegrationTestUtils.createConsumer(
                    kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(null),
                    List.of("dlq-topic", "first-output-topic", "second-output-topic")
            )
    ) {
        kafkaTemplate.send(new ProducerRecord<>(getInputTopicName(), key, value)).get();

        var result = KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(consumer, Duration.ofSeconds(60), 2);

        var firstResult = result.records("first-output-topic");
        var secondResult = result.records("second-output-topic");
        var dlqResult = result.records("dlq-topic");

I'm getting expected results. So it looks like sequential getRecords calls does not work for some reason.
